# C string based programming code

Tags: c, string

Can anyone please provide me the code in c programming language of problem in which we enter "ABCD"  as an input in run time  and we get "ZYXW"  as output and I tried to solve this using ASCII Code

Comment: SO is not a place where we just give you answers. Post what you have already tried to do, and someone will help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is an attempt to commission a programming work and not a question about programming or software development.

Comment: `char inp[] = "ABCD";
 for(const char *s = inp; *s; ++s)
  putchar('Z'-(*s-'A'));`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY `scanf("ABCD"); puts("ZYXW");`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Hope this will help you . Read about ascii code of character . Also you have to gain knowledge of pointer and string .

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    char ch[20];
    scanf("%s",ch);
    for(const char *s = ch; *s; ++s)
        putchar('Z'-(*s-'A'));
    return 0;
}
```